# Get all objects where optional exists in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, realm

If I have an optional var in my realm object, how would I get all instances an array of all instances where that var has not been set. For instance, get all instances of the `Person` who do not have an `Address`? Or all that **do** have an `Address`?

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var address: Address?
    // more values
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this expression

```
var personWhoAddressNil = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("address = nil")
```